# Twilio registration process

Tags: twilio

I'm looking to hire someone familiar with the Twilio registration process. I am an ISV, i.e. I don't send any texts on my own behalf, rather, I sell a product to my clients that myclients use to send texts.

I can't get through to anyone at Twilio who has time to work through this with me, but I can't be the only ISV trying to do this.

Anyone?

Thanks,
Steven

I have a brand and a campaign on Twilio, but I don't know how to "register" my client's phone numbers.

Comment: Where did you get stuck in the ISV Onboarding Walk Through? https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/a2p-10dlc/onboarding-isv-api

Comment: Understanding whether each sub-account requires a brand and a campaign at the sub-account level. Or if I can create a single brand and/or campaign to be shared by all subaccounts.  Do I need to ask my clients to give me their EIN number?  who "holds" the Brand registratiton, me or my client?

Comment: Step 1 is to add a profile for each subaccount: https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/a2p-10dlc/onboarding-isv-api#1-create-secondary-customer-profiles-and-attach-required-information. And, there is this note "For purposes of A2P registration, your ultimate objective in Sections 1-3 of this guide is to register an A2P Brand for your secondary customer."

Comment: Must I ask each of 100 or so clients to send me their EIN, physical address, etc.? Is there a way to "finesse" it?